# Do "my cold is not over yet" and "I am not over my cold yet" mean roughly the same?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

It seems that dictionaries suggest using this structure: "**somebody + to be / get + over + an illness**".

For example, "**I am not over my cold yet**".

Can we say "**my cold is not over yet**", and is it correct to say so?

Comment: You could say it, but I think "I haven't got over my cold yet", or your version, would be more idiomatic.

Comment: The dictionary is correct. Saying #2 will get you odd looks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They are slightly different uses of the word over, but idiomatically your two sentences mean the same thing.

> my cold is not over yet.

Here, "over" means completed, finished, like we might say "the game is over".

> I am not over my cold yet.

Here, "over" means "recovered from", like we might say "I'm over my breakup".

It is very similar usage to:

> You should **not** do that in **any circumstance**.

> You should in **no circumstances** do that.